# Is the email sent form Java web-app over https connection encrypted?

Tags: java, email, encryption, https, man-in-the-middle

I'm working on a Java web-application which runs on Https connection. This application sends emails to its users. I want to protect those emails from Man-in-the-middle attack and other potential threats. My questions are:

- Q1 : Do I need to encrypt my email content. (Why & How)/ Why not?
- Q2 : Doesn't https encrypts the data transmitted automatically?
- Q3 : If I have to encrypt them manually, how the receivers will decrypt it?
- Q4 : Whatever solution you suggest, What is the likelihood & severity of potential threats?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about email security and not about programming. It might be suitable for http://security.stackexchange.com/